# Why the heap did not corrupt earlier?

Tags: c, memory-management, heap-memory

I am trying to understand at a lower level how C manages memory. I have found some code on a webpage, whose aim is teaching you how bad can be poor memory management - so I copied and pasted it, and compiled:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        char *p, *q;
        p = malloc(1024);
        q = malloc(1024);
        if (argc >= 2)
                strcpy(p, argv[1]);
        free(q);
        free(p);
        return 0;
}
```

The test cases were executed with the generic command

```
/development/heapbug$ ./heapbug `perl -e 'print "A"x$K'`
```

For `$K < 1023` I did not expect problems, but for `$K = 1024` I expected a core dump, which didn't take place. Long story short, I started having segfaults for `$K > 1033`.

Two questions:
1) why did this happen?
2) is there a formula that states the "tolerance" of a system?

Comment: UB doesn't conform to "formulas."  Hence the word "undefined."

Comment: There is no "how C manages memory".  There is only how *specific C implementations* manage memory, and that varies.  I'm not personally inclined to attribute much value to studying the idiosyncrasies of specific implementations.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I meant - would this one be a side effect of memory paging?

Answer (score 6):

When you write past the bounds of allocated memory, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This means you can't accurately predict the behavior of the program.  It may crash, it may output strange results, or it may appear to work properly.

Also, making a seemingly unrelated change such as adding an unused local variable or a `printf` call for debugging can change how undefined behavior manifests itself, as can compiling with a different compiler or with the same compiler with different optimization settings.

Just because the program *could* crash doesn't mean it *will*.

That being said, what *probably* happened has to do with how `malloc` is implemented on your system.  It probably puts aside a few more bytes than what was requested for alignment and bookkeeping purposes.  Without aggressive optimization those extra bytes for alignment probably aren't used for anything else so you get awya with writing to them, but then you have problems when you write further into bytes than might contain internal structures used by `malloc` and `free` that you corrupt.

But again, you can't depend on this behavior.  C depends on the developer to follow the rules, and if you don't bad things happen.

Answer (score 3):

Undefined behaviour is just that. It might crash. It might not. It might work flawlessly. It might drink all the milk in your fridge. It might steal your favourite pair of shoes and stomp around in the mud with them.

Just because something is undefined behaviour does not mean it will be immediately obvious as such. You've overflowed the buffer here but the consequences weren't observed. It's likely because you don't actually use the second buffer you allocate, so if you started writing data to that there's no impact to any code.

This is why tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) exist, to look for mistakes that may not always produce obvious or undesirable results.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, if you overflow into memory controlled in the user space of your application(code/stack/etc) it isn't guaranteed to cause a coredump and can indeed overwrite some of that memory which is the risk identified by unintentional buffer overflows.

Once you start attempting to overwrite data outside of those bounds, the OS is more likely to block it.

Answer (score 1):

Writing to unallocated memory is undefined behavior. The outcome isn't specified. It may or may not cause a crash. A [heap overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_overflow) may corrupt the contents of other memory addresses, but how that will affect the program is unknown.